# Why does localStorage.getData('lists') does not work?

Tags: javascript

I am running this on localhost. I called this function and this error came up:

> Uncaught TypeError: localStorage.getData is not a function

```
function updateSession() {
    var str = "";
    for(var i = 0; i < listName.length; i++)
    {
        str += listName[i] + '\n';
    }
    localStorage.setData('lists', str);
}
```

Comment: Your error says `localStorage.getData`, but that function isn't in your question.  Please add the relevant code to your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you want is to

```
localStorage.setItem('lists', 'str');
```

and

```
const list1 = localStorage.getItem('lists');
```

getData is not a valid method for localStorage or sessionStorage